# How to write independent functional test

Tags: tdd, bdd

I really don't get how to write an "independent" behavior test.

E.G. A user can add an address to address book.

So I have an address book class. I write a test to add an address. But how do I verify that the address is successfully written without calling a "display address" method? When I call the "display address" method, I am depending on the display method being functional and working. Even then, isn't that testing two behaviors in one test?

Or if I dig into the database for verification, isn't that tie-ing the "behavior" to the implementation?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're saving the addresses down to the database at some point, implying that either

a) the address book needs to expose the added addresses in some way - via either a "GetAddresses" method, or an "AddedAddresses" public property - so they can be picked up and saved by some other object (sounds most likely from what you said); or

b) you've got some kind of "Save" method on the address book class, which fires off an operation to save the addresses to the DB, implying that within your address book class, you have a dependency on some other object, such as a repository or data access class.

If a), then you need to call that method or property to ensure the addresses have been added as you expect. If b), then you can supply a fake dataaccess class to the address book, expose a public property on that fake, call the "Save" method on the address book, and do your verification on the public "Addresses" property of the fake data access class, something like this:

(You didn't mention the language so this is just pseudo code)

```
class addressbook

    private _dataAccess
    private addresses

    constructor (dataaccess) _dataAccess = dataAccess

    public method AddAddress(address) addresses.add(address)

    public method save() _dataaccess.save(addresses)



class fakedataaccess

    public addresses

    public method save(addresses) addresses = addresses


{test}
public test AddingAddressesWorks

    fake = new fakedataaccess
    book = new addressbook(fake)

    // Do stuff to add addresses to addressbook

    book.save

    assert fake.addresses == the_addresses_i_added
```

Hopefully that makes sense. You could also achieve this with a mock, but that's beyond the scope of my pseudocode-fu, and the concept is the same anyway.

But either way, you're right that you will need to call something else (and therefore could argue that you're testing another construct) in order to verify what you want to verify.

Personally, if it were me, i'd be putting a public "Addresses" property on the address book.

Comment: This is more a unit test than functional test isn't it? I'm talking about something more alone the lines of hosting the application and posting data to a page, just to make sure the whole application is working.

Comment: You're talking about an integration test then, in which case you should push some known inputs into the page you mentioned to invoke the process, read the database results and verify they are what you're expecting, then clean up after yourself (ie, remove data from DB). To answer your initial question then, testing the "implementation" is exactly what integration tests are for, and so in this case, do it and don't feel bad.